# Linux-C Read data from shared memory it's corrupted

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

im writing and reading from shared memory a string.
Here it´s my code:

This is the writer (i have ommited unrelated code)

```
int main() {

    char message[MAX_BUF];
    key_t key;
    int sharedMemoryId;
    int semaphoreId;
    char *vc1;
    char *data;
    pid_t p3;
    struct sembuf operations[1];

    printf("start p2\n");

    saveMesageInBuffer(message); //This reads message from pipe and saves into message variable

    if(message==NULL){
      return -1;
    }

    key = getKeyForFile();

    if(key != -1){

      sharedMemoryId = createSharedMemoryId(key);
      if(sharedMemoryId!=-1){
        vc1 = shareContentInMemoryId(sharedMemoryId);
      }

      switch(p3 = fork()){
        case -1: 
            printf("Error");
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("run\n");
            execl("./Ej3", "Ej3", NULL);
            break;
        default:
            sleep(SECONDS);
            writeMessageInSharedVariable(vc1, message);
            pause();
            break;
    }

    } else {
       printf("Error getting key for file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    return 0;
}

void writeMessageInSharedVariable(char *dest, char *message){
  printf("El proceso P2 (PID=%d, Ej2) transmite un mensaje al proceso P3 a traves de una variable en memoria compartida\n", getpid());
  strncpy(dest, message, MAX_BUF);
}

int createSharedMemoryId(key_t key){
  return shmget(key, MAX_BUF, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
}

char* shareContentInMemoryId(int memoryId){
  return shmat(memoryId, (void *)0, 0);
}

key_t getKeyForFile(){
  char filePath[1024];
  if (getcwd(filePath, sizeof(filePath)) != NULL){
        strcat(filePath, "/");
        strcat(filePath, FIFO_FILE_NAME);
        return ftok(filePath, 0777);
  } else {
    return (key_t) -1;
  }
}
```

`

This is the reader (compiled as Ej3 and launched via fork and exec from writer)

```
int main() {
    key_t key;
    char message[MAX_BUF];
    int sharedMemoryId;
    char* vc1;

    printf("el 33 \n");

    key = getKeyForFile();
        if(key != -1){
        sharedMemoryId = createSharedMemoryId(key, sizeof(message));
        sleep(3);
        printf("continua\n");
        vc1 = (char*)shmat(sharedMemoryId, (void *)0, 0);
        if (vc1 == (char *)(-1)) {
            perror("shmat");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Readed %s\n", vc1);

    } else {
        printf("Error getting key for file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

}
```

I´m writting test in message and this is the result while i read it.

Readed test�[]���w�

Comment: Clearly you are missing the terminating zero. So it's not "corrupted" at all.

Comment: Sorry, i don´t understand u

Comment: @colymore The `%s` format is for printing a C string, which is an array of bytes with an ending null byte. You're not putting the null byte at the end of the string in the shared memory, so you print the garbage after it.

Answer (score 3):

`strncpy(dest, message, MAX_BUF);`

[`strncpy` doesn't null-terminate the buffer](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html).
You must null-terminate it by yourself.

```
strncpy(dest, message, MAX_BUF);
dest[MAX_BUF-1] = '\0'; /* <- like this */
```

`printf(%s` takes C-string which is a char array with a null character at the end. If you don't null-terminate the string, `printf` will not know when to stop, thus the garbage output.